# How would one decide on which parts of SSADM and UML methods to use in practice?

Tags: uml, modeling

I'm wondering how would one decide on what elements of SSADM and UML to incorporate into a project, as in why you would use a certain aspect of SSADM rather than an aspect of UML for example. Also, would the amount of data associated with a project affect the decision?

Comment: Look for architectural profiles like Zachman and TOGAF. Your question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

1. SSADM is a method, UML is a language. They differ in use very much.
2. SSADM is a whole, waterfall method. According to SSADM, you should use SSADM. Of course, you can use any piece of any method in your project, but if you do not use whole SSADM, it is not up to SSADM. If you have not the general concept how to develop, you can use SSADM or take it as a base. If you have some, but you are not content with some places, you can borrow them from SSADM, if appropriate steps are elaborated there better.
3. As for UML, you can use any its diagram in any process. It is only a way of presentation of some concepts. And additionally, a translation in one more language always gives you more power to catch errors on earlier stages. So, you can use UML diagrams for error filtering for more complicated parts of our project or for creation more formal documents to pass between stages of development.